# server http doesn't work while updating php file via ftp

Tags: php, nginx, ftp, httpserver, filezilla

when I update a php file via ftp (filezilla), pages using that file stop to work until transfer is complete. The server is linux with nginx/php-fpm, but I had the same problem with apache. The only "solution" I found is to edit directly the php file on a server remote shell, and update the content. But this is a very uncomfortable solution.
Is there anybody with a better solution?
Thanks

Comment: What combination of slow internet connection and massive file sizes are you dealing with, if this becomes an actual issue …?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal if you are doing upload via FTP. the Best solution is using Continues Deployment services with zero downtime approach.

[Continuous deployment without downtime](https://circleci.com/blog/continuous-deployment-without-downtime/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAvc_xBRCYARIsAC5QT9nAI9Ki-pJRmAO6DbZnoTiBGUzlXi6zSzFvJmxTZJwDGuuzTpPeJz0aAoNbEALw_wcB)

But if you talk about one file. You can just check php file if it exists or correct uploaded file else you can use old copy of this file.

Somesthing like this :

```
$file = 'uploaded.php';
$oldFile = 'uploaded_old.php';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    require_once($file);
} else {
    require_once($oldFile);
}
```